# Alerts not Being Added in Calendar list?

Tags: 2013, calendar, alert

I'm trying to add an OOTB alert to a **Calendar list** where it sends and e-mail to someone whenever a **new event is added**. I've created the alert, but I can't find it anywhere. I created it by selecting '**Set alert on this list**', but it doesn't appear in 'manage my alerts'. Can someone help?

I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you've created it for someone else, you won't see it under "Manage my alerts" as it technically isn't yours.  The person you've created it for would get an email that an alert was created, and they would have to manage it.  I tested this on my Office 365 Sharepoint Online tenant, and this was the behavior.